# Fade Animation (UIViewAnimation)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, view

At this point, I am working with simple view switching, and now I'm working with animation while switching views in xcode. However, my knowledge is not extensive on the topic, and I have spent about an hour researching this question before posting, so I have tried,

All I want to do is simply fade to the next view. I don't know if there is an animation for it, but what I am doing is making the app fade to black on a certain orientation for practice. However, if there is a better animation that you could suggest, please do so. Thanks!

-Jake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the crux of your question "All I want to do is simply fade to the next view." Then this is achieved very easily with the modal transition style. Assume for this example you have a `UIViewController` subclass named Alternate to which you want to transition.

```
Alternate *alt = [[Alternate alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
alt.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:alt animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I had to search for the dismiss animation part to go back though, but thanks again!